# mysql - Consulta para converter colunas em linhas

Tags: mysql, google-charts

Tenho minha consulta:

```
SELECT inscricao, assiduos_a1, assiduos_a2, max(data_inclusao)
  FROM cli_agendados_assiduos
 WHERE INSCRICAO = 10357410;
```

Que retorna:

```
inscricao   assiduos_a1 assiduos_a2 max(data_inclusao)
10357410    337         508         08/01/2015 14:54:48
```

Mas eu preciso dos resultados em linhas:

```
Label       Valor   Inscrição   max(data_inclusao)
assiduos_a1 337     10357410    08/01/2015 14:54
assiduos_a2 508     10357410    08/01/2015 14:54
```

somente desta forma meu gráfico (pie chart google) funcionará corretamente

Answer (score 1):

Só consegui pensar em algo como:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'assiduos_a1' AS 'Label', assiduos_a1 AS 'Valor', inscricao, max(data_inclusao)
    FROM cli_agendados_assiduos
    UNION
    SELECT 'assiduos_a2' AS 'Label', assiduos_a2 AS 'Valor', inscricao, max(data_inclusao)
    FROM cli_agendados_assiduos
) a
WHERE inscricao = 10357410;
```

Mas acho melhor você repensar a estrutura da sua tabela. Pesquise sobre "Pivot tables".